# Adding bindingRedirect(s) to the app.config file when new reference is added

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

Following an answer by Hans Passant to a previous question of mine I am coming to the conclusion that I need to add some bindingRedirects to the `app.config` file of the application that is referencing my assembly. I have found a fair bit of information about reading and writing to the app config file, but it all seems to deal with doing it at runtime. I need to do this before then.

Essentially if you as a developer were to reference the assembly that I'm currently working on then as you add it as a reference to your project I would like it to add bindingRedirect(s) to the `app.config` file of your project rather than having you to actually have to alter the `app.config` file yourself.

Is this actually possible, and if so how?

Assuming that this is possible then could I at the same time run through the existing references in your project and pull out the new version numbers that I need to add into my redirects  prior to adding those redirects into your `app.config` file?

I'll apologise in advance if I'm getting aspects of the nomenclature wrong, this is all new stuff to me and I'm having to do some rapid learning. All very enjoyable but equally easy to pick up incorrect terms along the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you codesign your assembly and publish it through nuget, then everyone who installs it using nuget will get binding redirects added automatically. See this thread: [Why are all my web.configs updated with an assembly redirect when installing autofac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164516/why-is-all-my-web-config-updated-with-an-assembly-redirect-when-installing-autof). With nuget you can also add manual config transforms which will be applied when someone installs your library: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations.